# Mockito throws NotAMockException in using when

Tags: java, unit-testing, amazon-web-services, mockito

It is my first use of Mockito, please see the code below. My goal is to ensure that that the code will throw `SecureStorageException`.

I am struggling with `NotAMockException` originated from the following line:

```
Mockito.doThrow(AmazonS3Exception.class).when(client).
getObject(Mockito.any(GetObjectRequest.class));
```

I tried `Mockito.spy` but probably I did not use this option correctly. So, the code below did not include this spy option.

```
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3ClientBuilder;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.GetObjectRequest;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.S3Object;
...
public class S3Test {
private static final String DEFAULT_S3_ENDPOINT = "s3-external-1.amazonaws.com";
private static final String S3_FILE_NOT_FOUND_ERROR_CODE = "NoSuchKey";
public static String S3_BUCKET_NAME = "aaa-test-" + Id.id();

@Mock
private AmazonS3 client;

@Before
public void setup() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard()
            .withEndpointConfiguration(new EndpointConfiguration(DEFAULT_S3_ENDPOINT, Regions.US_EAST_1.getName()))
            .build();
}

@Rule
public ExpectedException thrown = ExpectedException.none();

@Test
public void testGetObjectWithAmazonS3Exception() {
    Mockito.doThrow(AmazonS3Exception.class).when(client).getObject(Mockito.any(GetObjectRequest.class));
    thrown.expect(SecureStorageException.class);
    String fileName = Id.id();
    Object obj = (S3Object) call(() -> client.getObject(new GetObjectRequest(S3_BUCKET_NAME, fileName)));
    System.out.println("Obj=" + obj);
}

private Object call(Callable code) {
    try {
        return code.call();
    } catch (AmazonServiceException ase) {
...
```

Comment: `client` is clearly not a mock, because it was not created by `Mockito.mock()`

Comment: Yeah, if `client` isn't a mock or spy, then your answer is pretty clear: it's not a mock. If you want to edit in your `spy`-using code, we can see if there's any clear reason why it wouldn't work. On the other hand, though, one reason _not to mock 3rd party classes_ is that _we don't really know which implementation your client builder is going to return, so we can't tell whether Mockito will be able to successfully spy on it. What functionality are you trying to test?

Comment: [Don't mock what you don't own](https://github.com/testdouble/contributing-tests/wiki/Don%27t-mock-what-you-don%27t-own).